# Beamer document class: nicely alligning different stuff

Tags: beamer

I have a frame with a large picture in the upper part. Under this picture, there's a caption in a small font size. Under that I want to use the itemize environment with two short lines of text. However, I would like to have 1) upon clicking the first line of text, 2) upon clicking once again a small picture which is aligned with the first line of text and 3) upon clicking once again the last line of text which is aligned with the first line of text, i.e., the bullets are on one line.

At the moment I am using the code below, but it does not align neatly as I want it too.

```
\subsection{} 
\begin{frame}{Title}
\vspace{-.7cm}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \includegraphics[]{}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-.8cm}
\begin{center}
\tiny
*Caption
\end{center}
\normalsize
\vspace{0cm}
\pause

\begin{columns}[b]
\begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{4cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2->{Text 1}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{5cm}
  \centering\vfill
\includegraphics<3->[]{}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\vspace{-3cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<4->{Text}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\subsection{} 
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}\par\vskip-6pt
{\tiny *Caption}
\end{figure}\pause

\begin{minipage}{.30\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2->{Test text 1}
\item<4->{Test text 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{minipage}~%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics<3->[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\end{overlayarea}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea was simply to use just one `itemize` environment and, after a request made in comments, switched from `columns` to `minipage`s (I also made some other simplifications to the original code, but they were not directly related to the issue in the question).

I wasn't sure about the desired alignment for the items and the second picture, so you might need to delete the `\raisebox` or use a different value for the argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I change the distance between the two aligned text lines and the second picture? I would like to place the picture closer to the text.

Comment: @Funzies In that case, a better option is to use `minipage`s instead of `columns`; please see my updated answer; change the width for the `minipage`s according to your needs.